# Find global maximum of InterpolatingFunction in interval but not maximum value

Tags: functions, maximum

I have InterpolatingFunction generated from experimental data with many local maxima, one major peak I need to find, and the tail that grouse much higher then major peak. I tried to find my peak with FindArgMax or FindMaximum functions but I was capable to find only the local maximum or maximum value of the function in the interval. I'm interested if there is function that allow to find global extremum of the function.

[image]

Comment: Up to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima), the standard term is "local maximum with the maximal maximum value".

Comment: `InterpolatingFunction`s are smooth and differentiable.  You can take the first and second derivative of your `InterpolatingFunction` and examine the value of your function wherever the derivative is zero and 2nd derivative is negative.

Comment: What you label as "Global maximum" is a local maximum. You can make it global by restricting the definition region.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example.

```
data = Table[{x, Exp[x]*Sin[2*x] + 1}, {x, 0, 10, 0.2}];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
f = Interpolation[data];
```

Following the usual way of calculus.

```
g = Derivative[1][f];
h=g';
cp =Select[ DeleteDuplicates[Table[x /. FindRoot[g[x], {x, j}], {j, 1, 9}]],h[#] < 0 &]
```

> {1.01606,  4.159,  7.30032}

```
vcp = [Table[{cp[[j]], f[cp[[j]]]}, {j, 1, Dimensions[cp][[1]]}]
```

> `{{1.01606, 3.47329},  {4.159,  58.2359},  {7.30032,  1325.3},}`

At last,

```
vcp[[Position[vcp, Max[vcp]][[1, 1]]]]
```

> `{7.30032, 1325.3}`

Edit. The second derivative has been used.

Answer (score 1):

Test function:

```
Clear[normal] ;
normal[amplitude_, center_, scale_][x_] := amplitude*Exp[-(x-center)^2/scale^2]
Clear[x, f] ;
f[x_] := Evaluate[normal[0.5, -0.1, 0.5][x] + normal[5.0, 10.5, 1.0][x] + normal[3.0, 4.0, 0.25][x] + normal[1.0, 5.0, 0.2][x]] ;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange->All]
```

Find peaks (region max will be excluded):

```
x = Range[ 0, 10.0, 0.01] ;
y = Map[f, x] ;
i = SortBy[FindPeaks[y,0, Padding->10], Last] // Last // First ;
{xmax, ymax} = {x[[i]], y[[i]]}
```

Polish with a local method:

```
FindMaximum[f[w], {w, xmax}]
```

Comment: You do not deal with an interpolating function as asked in the question.